# How to install MIR display server?

Tags: 14.04, unity, software-installation, mir

I'd like to test/run Ubuntu QML apps on the MIR Desktop preview that should be available with 14.04.

What are the steps needed to enable a native MIR desktop (preview) session?

Comment: @fossfreedom: That wouldn't be intuitively known, will it? That unity 8 uses MIR.

Comment: I'm thinking that the question title is valid - but duping the question so that everyone who searches finds the correct question & answer

Comment: Ok, lets do this, since both titles are essentially the same question, lets SE SEO do it's magic ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in time for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS the Unity team has landed more improvements to make Unity 8 a feasible preview. It's not installed by default of course as it doesn’t meet the quality criteria for an LTS release.

You can install it from the Ubuntu archives via:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install unity8-desktop-session-mir
```

Logging out of Unity 7 should then give both options in the login screen:

[image]

**Note**: This package is provided for evaluation and demonstration purposes only.

Sources:

- http://www.olli-ries.com/unity-8-on-ubuntu-14-04/
- http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/02/unity-8-desktop-preview-session-14-04